# How to use the actions of the actors in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'd like to know if someone has already used Actions in the actors, and how to use them. I don't know how. I want to rotate an Actor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is Actor.action([Action](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Action.java) action), that will add an action to the [Actor](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.java) and it will be updated when Actor.act(delta) is called.

Here is an example code to [rotate](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/RotateTo.java) 90 degrees in 5 seconds a window:

```
Window window = new Window(...);
window.action(RotateTo.$(90, 5f));
```

This will automatically works if you have the widget on the Stage and you are calling stage.act(delta) correctly. Otherwise you will have to call Actor.act(delta) by yourself.

Hope it helps.